# Was mache ich mit den Satzzeichen in einer Frage, in der am Ende ein Zitat steht?

Tags: punctuation

Beipielsatz:

> Wie übersetze ich den Satz "Gras ist grün."?

Sind die Satzzeichen so richtig? Soll das Zitat mit einem Punkt enden? Gehört das Fragezeichen innerhalb oder außerhalb der Anführungszeichen?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Die Zeichensetzung bei nachgestellter direkter Rede oder bei Zitaten hängt davon ab, ob der zitierte Satz mit einem Punkt oder mit einem Ruf- oder Fragezeichen endet.

Wenn der Satz der direkten Rede (oder der zitierte Satz) mit einem Punkt endet, entfällt der Punkt des vorangehenden Satzes. Dabei muss noch unterschieden werden, ob vor dem Zitat ein Doppelpunkt steht oder nicht. Dieses Kriterium bestimmt, ob der Punkt *vor* oder *nach* dem letzten Anführungszeichen steht:

> Der Angeklagte antwortete auf die Frage des Richters: "Nicht schuldig."

und

> Der Angeklagte antwortete auf die Frage des Richters mit einem "Nicht schuldig".

Wenn der Satz vor der direkten Rede oder dem Zitat jedoch mit einem Rufzeichen oder einem Fragezeichen endet und der zitierte Satz mit einem Punkt, werden Ruf- oder Fragezeichen des Rahmensatzes geschrieben, während der Punkt beim Zitat entfällt. Also lautet das obige Beispiel richtig:

> Wie übersetze ich den Satz "Gras ist grün"?

Wenn sowohl der zitierte Satz als auch der davor ein Ruf- oder Fragezeichen verlangen, dann bleiben alle Satzzeichen erhalten. Beispiele:

> Lasst uns alle rufen "Alles Gute!"!
>   Wer stellte die Frage "Warum hast du mich verlassen?"?

Das sieht zwar etwas seltsam aus – aber so ist die Regel.

Comment: Your scholarly and insightful answers are always appreciated.

Comment: Wundert mich, dass es mal etwas so logisches gibt wie `Wer stellte die Frage "Warum hast du mich verlassen?"?`! :)

Comment: "aber so ist die Regel." - Das sollte man vielleicht auch belegen: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibregeln/anfuehrungszeichen bzw. §§ 90-94.

Comment: @musiKk eines Tages wird Duden auf german.stackexchange.com verlinken. ;-)